# My app cannot find my images' paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, debugging, error-handling, path

I have my images stored in `/rubyprograms/search/public/urlimages`. I checked through my terminal to make sure that path is there and that all of the images are inside it. I link to the images, for example, at this path: `/­rubyprograms/­search/­public/­urlimages/­2173513720.­jpg` but my app cannot seem to find the image. For example, this is an error in my logs:

```
Started GET "/rubyprograms/search/public/urlimages/2173486240.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jul 07 21:34:23 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/rubyprograms/search/public/urlimages/2173486240.jpg"):
```

However I know the images are there at that route. Why is this happening?

Comment: What directory is your app in?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612531/carrierwave-problem-with-path-to-image

Comment: @vonconrad my app is in `/search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is in `/rubyprograms/search`, the `public/` directory will be used as the **root** directory for all non-Rails requests.

Because of this, the correct path to the images would be `/urlimages/2173486240.jpg`.

Rails has a handy helper for images, called `image_tag`, which essentially creates image tags for you. The usage is:

```
<%= image_tag('2173486240.jpg') %>
# will create <img src="/images/2173486240.jpg" alt="" />
```

Please note that this will create the entire html tag, and assume that you have your images in `public/images/`.

Answer (score -1):

Public has to be in the root directory.

```
`/rubyprograms/search/public/urlimages/2173486240.jpg`
```

Needs to be

```
`/rubyprograms/public/urlimages/2173486240.jpg`
```

If you wand to follow COC.

Comment: `/search` is the root directory, no? It's what holds my `/app`, `/config`, `/lib`, and `/db` directories. `/rubyprograms` is just what holds my `/search` directory. Also, what do you mean by COC?

Comment: I think rails uses the name public. That is the convention. So logically it's the same thing but that first directory needs to be name public.

Comment: ok so maybe I should take the `/urlimages` directory out of `/public` and directly into `/search`?

Comment: You need to have your images in your public directory as defined from the git go or you will need to change how rails works.